# How can I use numpy functions within NumbaPro functions?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to CUDA, I am trying to use NumbaPro's cuda extension to compute some exponentials, however I cannot seem to use numpy within the cuda complied functions? I know i am doing something silly, but I cannot figure it out.

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import imshow, show, plot
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numbapro import cuda
from numba import *
import math


def Deng_test(xx,Expre):
    ExTest                              = (np.abs(np.sum(Expre)))**2
    return ExTest

Deng_test_gpu = cuda.jit(argtypes=(double,complex128), restype=float64, device=True, inline=True)(Deng_test)
```

Comment: I suspect that you cannot use arbitrary numpy functions in CUDA-Python.  Probably you are restricted to [what is imported from numbapro.cuda](http://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/CUDAJit.html) and what is in the [cuda python specification](http://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/CUDAPySpec.html).